# Null check operator used on a null value on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have two lines of codes that are giving me an error of "Null check operator used on a null value". I tried various methods but couldn't figure out a valid one. Can anyone help me fix?

```
var chatRoomId = getChatRoomIdByUsernames(myUserName!, username);
```

and

```
        SharedPreferenceHelper().saveUserName(userDetails.email!.replaceAll("@gmail.com", ""));
```

Comment: When you write `variable!`, you are making a personal guarantee that `variable` will not be `null`.  Since that assertion is evidently not true, you instead must *check* whether `variable` is `null` first (e.g. with an `if` statement, with the conditional ternary operator, with the `??` operator, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
myUserName ?? '';
```

and as soon as possible search about "dart null safety".

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ! (null check operator) on null value

You have to use it like this

```
var chatRoomId = getChatRoomIdByUsernames(myUserName ?? '', username);
```